# How to combine/aggregate classification accuracies from binary one-vs-one classifiers to get final accuracy equivalent a multiclass classifier?

Tags: classification, python, svm, scikit-learn, multi-class

Consider a `3` class data, say, *Iris data*.

Suppose we want do binary *SVM* classification for this multiclass data using *Python's sklearn*. So we have the following three binary classification problems: `{class1, class2}, {class1, class3}, {class2, class3}`.

For each of the above problem, we can get a *classification accuracy, say, 60%, 70%, 80%.

I have the following question:

How to combine the results of these `3` binary classifiers and get a result equivalent to a multiclass classifier, i.e., how to get the final *classification accuracy, precision, recall, f1-score and a 3x3 confusion matrix* after combining accuracies, precisions, recalls, f1-scores and 2x2 confusion matrices obtained from binary classifiers?

```
import pandas as pd
    import numpy as np
    from sklearn.model_selection import KFold
    from sklearn import svm, datasets
    from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score, f1_score, precision_score, recall_score, classification_report, confusion_matrix
    import time
    import os

    tic = time.clock()
    # Import data
    iris = datasets.load_iris()
    X = iris.data                    
    Y = iris.target

    # Now, suppose we have three separate sets {data1, target1}, {data2, target2}, {data3, target3}
    # for binaray classification.

    #dataset = [{data1 + data2, target1 + target2}, {data1+ data3, target1 + target3}, {data2 + data3, target2 + target3}]

    for d in dataset:

        #Import any pair, say, {data1 + data2, target1 + target2}. We will import 3 pairs one-by-one for 3 different binary classification problems.

        #data = data1 + data2
        #label = target1 + target2

        K = 10    #Number of folds
        for i in range(K):
            kf = KFold(n_splits=K, random_state=None, shuffle=False)

            cv = list(kf.split(data1))        
            trainIndex, testIndex = cv[i][0], cv[i][1]        
            trainData, testData = data.iloc[trainIndex], data.iloc[testIndex]
            trainData_label, testData_label = data_labe.iloc[trainIndex], data_labe.iloc[testIndex]

            # So now, we have Train, Test, Train_label, Test_label


            clf = []
            clf = svm.SVC(kernel='rbf')

            clf.fit(Train, Train_label)     

            predicted_label = clf.predict(Test)


            Accuracy_Score = accuracy_score(Test_label, predicted_label)
            Precision_Score = precision_score(Test_label, predicted_label,  average="macro")
            Recall_Score = recall_score(Test_label, predicted_label,  average="macro")
            F1_Score = f1_score(Test_label, predicted_label,  average="macro")

            print('Average Accuracy: %0.2f +/- (%0.1f) %%' % (Accuracy_Score.mean()*100, Accuracy_Score.std()*100))
            print('Average Precision: %0.2f +/- (%0.1f) %%' % (Precision_Score.mean()*100, Precision_Score.std()*100))
            print('Average Recall: %0.2f +/- (%0.1f) %%' % (Recall_Score.mean()*100, Recall_Score.std()*100))
            print('Average F1-Score: %0.2f +/- (%0.1f) %%' % (F1_Score.mean()*100, F1_Score.std()*100))

            CM = confusion_matrix(Test_label, predicted_label)

        print('-------------------------------------------------------------------------------')
    toc = time.clock()
    print("Total time to run the complete code = ", toc-tic)
```

Also, how would we combine the accuracies if we also did *10-fold cross-validation*?

Comment: Why not just do multiclass classification?

Comment: because I will like to learn.

Comment: Have a look at https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/231/how-to-get-an-aggregate-confusion-matrix-from-n-different-classifications

Comment: That gives some theoretical idea without any implementation. In my example above I gave the Python implementation. I am expecting an answer with implementation.