# How to perform kFold cross validation in Libsvm's precomputed kernel in MATLAB?

Tags: cross-validation, svm, matlab, libsvm, rbf-kernel

I understand that `Libsvm` provides `'v 10'` option for `10`-fold cross-validation in`SVM` classification. Here is the MATLAB code line:

```
model = svmtrain(TrainLabels, K, '-t 4', 'v 10');
```

However, it gives an empty model. How to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`svmtrain` function in `Libsvm` takes the options together as a whole string. For example, in your case your *option string* must be '-t 4 -v 10'. Not separated as two parameters. If your Kernel matrix is correctly formatted, you should have no problem. And keep in mind that, in any usage type of usage violation, the library returns an empty model; and there should be a warning message on the console, indicating the problem. A final warning: please check that your current library version supports type 4 svm, i.e. '-t 4'.

Comment: can you please also explain how to do grid search over `rbf` kernel's `C` and `gamma` parameters using `Libsvm` in MATLAB? I wonder if you can also take a moment to help with my other question at: [link](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/368372/how-to-combine-aggregate-classification-accuracies-from-binary-one-vs-one-classi?noredirect=1#comment692551_368372)

Comment: I don't see any other solution than two nested loops because if you check parse_command_line function in https://github.com/cjlin1/libsvm/blob/master/matlab/svmtrain.c , the string after -c or any other parameter is directly converted to float (i.e. no array handling).

Comment: @gunes what range of values for C and gamma libsvm consider when doing cross validation using -v 5 ?